Python typing - Return derived classes in overridden methods
I have an abstract base class that defines a function to return a list with elements inheriting from a specific class.
I want to define subclasses that implements this ABC, and returns instances of specific subclasses. However, mypy won't allow it, and claims that I have incompatible return types.
The following example highlight what I'm trying to achieve.
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import override


class Base:
    pass


class Derived(Base):
    pass


class Abstract(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> list[Base]: ...


# This should pass because foo returns a list of Derived, which is a subclass of Base
class ConcreteShouldPass(Abstract):
    @override
    def foo(self) -> list[Derived]:
        return [Derived()]


# This should fail because foo returns a list of str, not Base
class ConcreteShouldFail(Abstract):
    @override
    def foo(self) -> list[str]:
        return ["foo"]

However, both ConcreteShouldPass and ConcreteShouldFail fails mypy with the following errors:
foo.py:20: error: Return type "list[Derived]" of "foo" incompatible with return type "list[Base]" in supertype "Abstract"  [override]
foo.py:26: error: Return type "list[str]" of "foo" incompatible with return type "list[Base]" in supertype "Abstract"  [override]

How can I get the implementation in ConcreteShouldPass to succeed, and the implementation in ConcreteShouldFail to fail type checking?

list is invariant, so list[Derived] is not assignable to list[Base] and your class violates LSP. To quickly see why, you can .append(OtherDerived()) to list[Base], but can't to list[Derived] - lists are mutable. In your case Abstract should be generic in base' type, and ConcreteShouldPass would inherit from Abstract[Derived]. There must be a good dupe for that, let me find it.

Thanks a lot @STerliakov - still need to understand LSP!
